# Express session is empty in Safari

Tags: node.js, express, session, safari

I'm building a Node.js application with express. I use express-session for sessions. The data I store in a session is available in IE, Chrome and Firefox. But in Safari the session is empty all the time. So when I do `console.log(req.session)` it prints:

```
Session {
  cookie: { 
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true 
   },
   userHasCheckCorrect: true 
 }
```

This are my settings in server.js

```
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true
    }
}));
```

It's a server with SSL certificate so it's a HTTPS domain. With HTTP it seems to work fine in Safari. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a setting I'm missing? I've looked on many places but couldn't find the answer yet. And why does it work in all browsers expect for Safari?

Comment: You need to enable safari cookies from the [settings](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21411?locale=en_US)

Comment: @anttud in the server.js settings? I can't find how I can possibly do that

Comment: From the Safari browser settings

Comment: But that only fixes the problem for me, isn't there a way to do this server side?

Comment: Nope, it is an client side issue. But if someone is using Safari they have probably enabled the cookies. You could add a popup to frontend telling them to enable cookies?

Comment: Pls is there any solution so far? I've tried to solve this issue but I was unable to

Answer (score 1):

With Safari it is required to pass in credentials: 'include' in request header, otherwise it doesn't send cookies.

You might also want to set a global response header after your set your session middleware by something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.set('credentials', 'include');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```